# Axios GET URL peculiar issue

Tags: javascript, node.js

**Problem:**
The function fetches the right response when the URL is hardcoded into `axios.get()` but doesn't work otherwise.

**Observations:**
I have observed that it picks the https://api.***.com/data/reports/calls/jobs and fetches that response but completely ignores the `jobID`

```
async function fetchJsonFileInChunks(jobID, token, chunkSize) {

  const headers = {
    'Authorization': `Bearer ${token}`
  };


  const URL = `https://api.***.com/data/reports/calls/jobs/${jobID}`;


  try {
    const response = await axios.get(URL, {headers, responseType: 'stream' });
    if (response.status === 200) {
      const readStream = response.data;

      const writeStream = fs.createWriteStream('output.json'); // Replace with your output file path

      // Create a Transform stream to process each chunk
      const transformStream = new stream.Transform({
        transform(chunk, encoding, callback) {
          // Process the chunk here (e.g., write it to the writeStream)
          this.push(chunk);
          callback();
        }
      });

      // Pipe the readStream through the transformStream to the writeStream
      readStream.pipe(transformStream).pipe(writeStream);

      return new Promise((resolve, reject) => {
        writeStream.on('finish', () => resolve());
        writeStream.on('error', (error) => reject(error));
      });
    } 
  } catch (error) {
    throw error.message;
  }
}
```

I have debugged the code for hours and have done all sorts of measures. There's nothing wrong with URL format or job ID format.

Comment: Did you try to get response using `then` method end of axios request?

Comment: Maybe your `jobID` has typo or Unicode characters?

Comment: If you're saying you hard-code a job ID in the URL and it works, and w/ the `jobID` interpolation it doesn't, then it's something about what's in `jobID`.

Comment: Yeah been calling it in the main() using then().catch()

Comment: jobID looks like xxxx-xxxx-xxxx-xxxxx

Comment: As the others said here too, the jobID doens't just get ignored based on the code you shared. It doesn't contain what you think it does.

Comment: or perhaps the endpoint doesn't take jobID ... the fact that it's `.../jobs` and not `.../job` makes me wonder if you're using the correct base URL - just a thought - though, that doesn't explain success when hard coded ... probably not the issue ... have you `console.log(URL)` to check?

Comment: Okay, the issue was related to the API actually. It would take a couple of minutes before it can generate a full report on a given `jobID`. I put a timer instead of immediately calling the `fetchJSONFileinChunks()`.